# Lebesgue measurability of a set considering its boundary

Tags: real-analysis

For any set $E\subset R^2$,the boundary $\partial E$ of $E$ is the closure of $E$ minus the interior of $E$. Then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable whenever $m(\partial E)=0$.

How can I start with it?

Comment: What kind of set is $E - \partial E$?

Comment: An open set in $R^2$.

Comment: So $E$ is the union of an open set and a set of measure $0$

Answer (score 1):

If the measure of the boundary is $0$ then $E$ differs from an open set by a set of measure zero. Hence it is Lebesgue measurable.